# Check for list of String in DataAnnotation

Tags: entity-framework, attributes, data-annotations

I need to check whether the Property contains one of the or all following strings

**"C-I", "C-II", "C-III", "C-IV", "C-V"**

if not it Errormessage must be

**"Invalid Property.  Must be blank or C-I, C-II, C-III, C-IV, or C-V.",**

i don know which "DataAnnotation Attribute" to use and How? if possible please provide sample.

Comment: This should be EF validation, or you need to validate user input, e.g. on ASP.NET MVC controller?

Comment: @sergeyBerezovskiy, can't i check like this with help of available attributes in dataannotation??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) data annotation.  However, I would recommend implementing `IValidatableObject` on your data class.  You can then write your custom logic within the `Validate` method.  This way, if/when those valid options change, you would just be modifying a collection, rather then trying to figure out a new valid regex statement.

Comment: thanx for reply. I handled in front layer.:)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using anyone of the follwing Attributes

**

> 1.EnumDataTypeAttribute
>   2.CustomValidationAttribute 
>   3. Creating New Custom Attribute.

**